# Telegram Bot sends same message many times PHP

Tags: php, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

I am writing a telegram to the php bot, it works fine, but it sends the same message many times, it needs to be sent once, can anyone help me? here is my code

```
function chat_telegram( )
{
    $token = <token>;
    $telegram = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" . $token;
    $query = http_build_query([
        'chat_id' => <chat_id>,
        'text' => 'I love pizza'
    ]);

    $response = file_get_contents( $telegram . '/sendMessage?' . $query );
    return $response;
}
```

Comment: May you show the usage of the function? The function itself seems fine.

Comment: I call the function in the header of my site, chat_telegram (), when I reload my site, the message is sent

Comment: So basically, every refresh of your site would send the message?

Comment: Where is the problem? If you reload, of course you send the same again. If you don't want send it more then once, don't do it. Use a database and store message hashes. When in DB do not send again.

Comment: at one reload is sent several times

Comment: can it be connected with the local host? I send text through the locale

Comment: yes, from online it works correctly